# Why does my label contain brackets from my array?

Tags: titanium

I am fairly new to all this so bear with me please. I want my label text to display my array information, but without the array brackets. Thanks in advance with any help.

```
var json = {
    basic: ['Name: James', 'Age: 31']
};

var basicInfo = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: json.basic

});
win3.add(basicInfo);

console.log(json.basic);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the label to display: 'Name: James', 'Age: 31'

You could try

```
    str = JSON.stringify(json.basic);
    var basicInfo = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: str.slice(1,str.length-1)
    });
```

This removes the first and last characters of the stringified version of json.basic. However, if you can, I highly suggest that you restructure the json data as:

```
    var json = {
        basic: {'Name': 'James', 'Age': 31}
    };
```

This makes basic an object and you can can access Name and Age as json.basic.Name and json.basic.Age, respectively. This is more intuitive as Name and Age are attributes, and thus shouldn't really be in an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great. I have much more to learn. Thank you for helping me.